# how to Each Order will be placed next to its previous Order Date?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

hi i'm begginer in sql Server. I have a table called sales.

```
OrderID | OrderDate | CustomerName
--------|-----------|------------
1       | 01-20-2000| Joe
--------|-----------|------------
2       | 01-19-2000|Rabert
--------|-----------|------------
3       |01-17-2000 |Alice
--------|-----------|------------
4       | 01-16-2000| Tome
--------|-----------|------------
5       | 01-15-2000|James
--------|-----------|------------
6       |01-10-2000 |Fred
--------|-----------|------------
7       | 01-09-2000| Luie
--------|-----------|------------
8       | 01-03-2000|Sara
--------|-----------|------------
9       |01-02-2000 |Nik
--------|-----------|------------
```

I want Each Order will be placed next to its previous day's Order.

For Example:

```
 OrderID         OrderDate   CusromerName    OrderID     OrderDate       CusromerDate
    1       2000 - 01 - 20      Joe         2       2000 - 01 - 19      Robert
    2       2000 - 01 - 19      Robert      3       2000 - 01 - 17      Alice
    3       2000 - 01 - 17      Alice       4       2000 - 01 - 16      Tom
    4       2000 - 01 - 16      Tom         5       2000 - 01 - 15      James
    5       2000 - 01 - 15      James       6       2000 - 01 - 10      Fred
    6       2000 - 01 - 10      Fred        7       2000 - 01 - 09      Luie
    7       2000 - 01 - 09      Luie        8       2000 - 01 - 03      Sara
    8       2000 - 01 - 03      Sara        9       2000 - 01 - 02      Nik
```

Comment: what you have done so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try it:

```
select o.*, prev.*
from Orders o
cross apply
 (
   select top 1 *
   from Orders P where P.OrderDate < O.OrderDate
   order by OrderDate DESC
 ) prev
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This way!!!!!

```
    select t1.*,
    lead(OrderID)over(  order by OrderDate desc) as OrderID,
    lead(OrderDate)over(   order by OrderDate desc) as OrderDate,
    lead(CustomerName)over(  order by OrderDate desc) as CustomerName    from #tt t1
```